# Bayesian SEM in AMOS - suggest resources?

Tags: bayesian, spss, structural-equation-modeling, amos

I'm looking for resources regarding Bayesian SEM estimation using `AMOS` built-in procedures (I have ordered categorical data).

Google gives some basic resources on theory, but not so much on implementation.

Can anyone recommend any worked examples?

Answer (score 1):

Finch, French, & Immekus (2016) is a good book that I have used in the past. Also, [this](https://helenagmartins.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/amos_tutorial.pdf) tutorial is good, as it has several great worked out examples. Both references discuss theory, but are much more application focused, so you should be fine.

**References**

Finch, H., French, B. F., & Immekus, J. C. (2016). Applied psychometrics using SPSS and AMOS. IAP.